# Trying to find all coordinate points within a certain range

Tags: python, pandas, csv, coordinates, gis

What I am trying to achieve here is that I have one **source csv file**, filled with coordinates and an additional **target csv file** with more coordinates from which I want to find all the coordinates in the **target csv file** that are with in certain range from every single coordinate in the **source csv file**.

The coordinates are formatted as **xx.xxxxxx** and **yy.yyyyyy**.

"lat1" and "long1" are the names of the coordinate columns in the source csv and "lat2" and "long2" are the coordinate columns in the target csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time 
from playsound import playsound

fast_df = pd.read_csv('target.csv') # 2
el_df = pd.read_csv('source.csv') # 1

"""
Commandos:
    
    coords_file.columns - get columns
    coords_file.drop_duplicates() - removes identical rows
    coords_flie.iloc[] - fetch row with index
    coords_file[['OBJEKT_ID', 'EXTERNID', 'DETALJTYP']]
    
"""


def findDistance(row, source_lat, source_long):
    # print(row, source_lat, source_long)
    row_lat = row['lat2']
    row_long = row['long2']
    lat_diff = np.abs(source_lat - row_lat)/0.00001 # divide by 0.00001 to convert to meter
    long_diff = np.abs(source_long - row_long)/0.00001
    row['Distance'] = np.sqrt(lat_diff**2+long_diff**2)
    return row

def findDistance_(source_coordinates, target_coordinates):
    lat_diff = np.abs(source_coordinates[0] - target_coordinates[0])/0.00001 # divide by 0.00001 to convert to meter
    long_diff = np.abs(source_coordinates[1] - target_coordinates[1])/0.00001
    Distance = np.sqrt(lat_diff**2+long_diff**2)
    easyDistanceReader(Distance)
    return Distance

def easyDistanceReader(Distance):
    if Distance > 1000:
        Distance = Distance/1000
        print("Distance:", Distance, "km")
    else:
        print("Distance:", Distance, "m")


def runProgram(target_df, source_df, distans_threshold):
    
    """
    Loop over coord in source.csv 
        --> Find all the coordinates within the interval in target.csv
    """
    
    "Using this in order to skip coordinates in source.csv which are outside the target.csv     area"
    latInterval = min(target_df['lat2']), max(target_df['lat2'])
    longInterval = min(target_df['long2']), max(target_df['long2'])
    
    "Find all relevant coordinates based on the source coordinates"
    source_df = source_df.loc[(source_df['lat1'].between(min(latInterval), max(latInterval))) &     (source_df['long1'].between(min(longInterval), max(longInterval)))]

    dataframes = []
    start = time.time()
    for index in range(len(source_df)):
        row = source_df.iloc[index]
        source_coordinates = row[['lat1','long1']]
        
        indices = []
        target_df = target_df.apply(findDistance, args=(row['lat1'],row['long1']), axis=1)
        
        relevantTargets = target_df.loc[target_df['Distance'] < distans_threshold]
        if len(relevantTargets) > 0:
            indices.append(relevantTargets.index[0])

        if len(indices) > 0:
            new_df = target_df.loc[indices]
            dataframes.append(new_df)
        
    final_df = pd.concat(dataframes)


    final_df = final_df.loc[:, final_df.columns != 'Distance'].drop_duplicates()
    print(final_df)
    
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed time per iteration:", end-start)
    
    final_df.to_csv('final.csv')
    playsound('audio.mp3')

runProgram(fast_df,el_df, 300) # This number indicates the distance in meters from source coordinates I want to find target coordinates.
```

The result I'm getting currently is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihCZw.gif). This is a result from when I'm running the code at 5000 meters. You can clearly see that a lot of the coordinate points are left out and I cannot figure out why. The black points are **source** points, the brown **target** points and the pink are the resulting points.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I already answered to similar question. Look at `BallTree` and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135900/15239951). You just have to change `tree.query(coords, k=1)` by `tree.query_radius(coords, r=5000, return_distance=True)`. Provide sample and expected output, please.

Answer (score 0):

The line `indices.append(relevantTargets.index[0])` seams to only append the first index of relevantTargets, when you want all of relevantTarget's indices. Try replacing this with `indices += [*relevantTargets.index]`. However, I don't know why you can't directly do `dataframes.append(relevantTargets)` here instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot man! My account is too novice, so I can't even give you an upvote. :<

Answer (score 0):

If I'm thinking about your question correctly, this approach may be simplified by using GeoPandas.sjoin_nearest [[link here]](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html). I've used the geopandas.sjoin module in the past to join points to intersecting polygons. I believe sjoin_nearest was just added in the most recent release.