# Minimum distance between coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, distance, geopy

I have a two pandas data frames, each containing a column with a tuple of coordinates (one for schools, the other for houses).

I would like to create a new column in the houses dataframe containing the shortest distance from any of the schools. Below is some code I tried but without success

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopy.distance

schools = pd.DataFrame([(29.775803, -95.56353), (40.060276, -83.004196), (40.70592, -74.010765)])
houses = pd.DataFrame([(41.291989997, -73.087632372), (41.16741635, -73.188437585), (41.038689564, -73.635282641), (40.825542, -96.60775)])

x = 0
minimum_distance = []
for i in t:
    for j in private:
        if geopy.distance.geodesic(i, j).km > x:
            v = geopy.distance.geodesic(i, j).km
            minimum_distance.append(v).km
        else:
            continue
schools['shortest_distance'] = minimum_distance
```

The house dataframe should look like this after:

```
    0   1   shortest_distance
0   41.291990   -73.087632  101.332983
1   41.167416   -73.188438  86.153595
2   41.038690   -73.635283  48.656830
3   40.825542   -96.607750  1156.075739
```

Does anyone have any idea how to perform this ? I used a double loop in my code because I don't think there is another way since each element has to be searched but I am also wondering how efficient it would be with 2 dataframe of 20000 rows each.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Louis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the distance between two geographic coordinates of two different dataframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70941094/how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-geographic-coordinates-of-two-different-data)

Comment: The second answer to this question is what you want - do a crossjoin, apply the dist function then you'll need to sort by dist and drop duplicates on house lat/long

Comment: Ok Chris thank you, i'll look at the other post and use your second comment afterwards. Thank you !